# Defining the Cache Manifest file within ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, caching, manifest

When using a cache manifest file within ASP.NET can I just add a standard text file called something like app.manifest? (which is then referenced from the html in each relevant page).

Or are there other considerations (such as mime type) that demand a more convoluted approach?

In this approach: http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2011/01/26/creating-html5-offline-web-applications-with-asp-net.aspx then Stephen Walther sets up the manifest as a handler.  Do I really have to do it that way in ASP.NET, or is there a 'simpler' way in ASP.NET?  Just striving for less code!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in sighted article, author has created a custom handler to server the manifest with correct MIME type. This is indeed a good way in ASP.NET where you don't have to touch web server configuration.

If you don't want to write such handler and wish to serve file directly such as "*app.manifest*" then you have to make sure to modify IIS configuration (for the web-site) map the correct MIME Type (`text/cache-manifest`) for `manifest` extension (see [this](http://www.hosting.com/support/dedicated/IIS/newmime) and [this](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/03/25/how-to-add-mime-types-with-iis7-web-config.aspx) for how to register a new MIME type in IIS)